# Blender plays a short .mp3 sound when it completes the render - HOW?

Tags: rendering, customization

I was looking into a really necessary function for me when using Blender. I need Blender to play a short mp3 sound when it finishes rendering.
I found this on the API:

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete

```
Callback list - on completion of render job
```

And this script .py (addon) sends email notification, but I was really looking for .mp3 playback of a sound. Say for example if you are away from the computer, then you´ll hear the render fininsh.
https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Notify_after_render/

But I don´t have a way to put this all together.
Could someone point me with another script?

Comment: I found this site with some useful information, maybe this will make it work? I´m on PC: https://blender3d.com.ua/avtomatizatsiya-renderinga/

Comment: Here, there's already an add-on for it. https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Auto_Save/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The `aud` module**

For a standard  the ubiquitous `wave` module to play ".wav" files would be a failsafe way to go.

However, Blender comes with the `aud` module which plays any format of sound that can be used in blender. My build supports:

```
>>> bpy.path.extensions_audio
frozenset({'.aac', '.oga', '.mka', '.eac3', '.aiff', '.aif', '.wav', '.mp2', '.ogg', '.flac', '.ac3', '.mp3', '.m4a', '.wma'})
```

Test script, edit the path to match path to audio file.

```
import bpy
import aud

path = "/home/batfinger/Music/CCR Chronicle, Vol. 1 - The 20 Greatest Hits/DISC/Creedence Clearwater Revival - Suzy Q. (Part 1) - 13.mp3"
# load the sound
snd = aud.Sound(path)
dev = aud.Device()

def finish_render(scene):
    dev.play(snd)
    return None

# clear others, assuming this is only one.    
bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.clear()
# assign handler.  
bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(finish_render)
```

Here is the way to stop the playback.

```
>>> import aud
>>> dev = aud.Device()
>>> dev.stopAll()
```

Comment: when you mention "here's a way to stop the playback": do you mean the sound keeps on playing with this script? I just want a short "blink.mp3" to play so I know afar that the render ended. Thanks. Great script.

Comment: Plays it once. I tested with a 10min song, so I thought I'd add how to stop sound.

Comment: yeah. I definetly test it with a quick .mp3. But this is good to know (how to stop it as well). Amazing. Thanks.!

Comment: This should really be an official plugin for Blender...