# Render finished notification on Windows

Tags: interface, windows

On Mac, when Blender finishes rendering, it sends a notification with an audible chime. But on Windows there is no notification. Is it a Mac-only feature, or I'm missing some settings? I googled for a while but this feature seems to be undocumented.

Comment: I never experienced it (windows) but this q&a could help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131940/blender-plays-a-short-mp3-sound-when-it-completes-the-render-how